# The best distribution of cameras inside a room

Tags: algorithm

my problem is to cover 100% of the room with cameras in 2D. The camera can be modelled as a polygon. I am finished with all the modelling and necessary tools. My problem is with the algorithm. The complexity of blind search for a big room with many obstacles will be too high.

So does anyone know a better (or optimal) algorithm?

Comment: a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds promising:

http://www.springerlink.com/content/u7gp44hchuhly6yg/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to consider obstacles, use a single 180 degree fish-eye lens mounted on one of the walls.

Comment: i can use even 360 degree if you see one of those, but the user enter the specification of the cameras to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Use two 180-degree cameras on walls that are 90 degrees to each other, assuming a room that is a square or rectangle.  With that, you get a redundancy for most of the room except for possibly the one corner that falls in between the cameras.

Comment: the specification of the camera and room are dynamics and entered from the user, so i can't assume anything.